# passport-google-oauth2 for fetching gmail.users.messages.list in node js

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, passport.js, gmail-api

First of all I am bit new to node js + oauth2 with passport so if you have any confusion please comment.

I have tried below for authentication with google from oauth2 with node.js, here is the code

```
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var google = require('googleapis');
var GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "---MY-CLIENT-ID";
var GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = "---MY-CLIENT-SECRET";
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
   res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
   res.render('login', { user: req.user });
});

// user back to this application at /auth/google/return

app.get('/auth/google',
   passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
function(req, res) {
   res.redirect('/');
});

// GET /auth/google/return
// Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
// request. If authentication fails, the user will be redirected back to the
// login page. Otherwise, the primary route function function will be called,
// which, in this example, will redirect the user to the home page.

app.get('/auth/google/return',
   passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
function(req, res) {
   res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
   req.logout();
   res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000);

// Simple route middleware to ensure user is authenticated.
// Use this route middleware on any resource that needs to be protected. If
// the request is authenticated (typically via a persistent login session),
// the request will proceed. Otherwise, the user will be redirected to the
// login page.

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login')
}
```

Above all is working fine but now I want to use this in with the help of passport for fetching the gmail's emails list.

```
   var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
   var profileData = gmail.users.messages.list({ userId: 'me', auth:    "**AUTHORISATION OBJECT WITH ACCESSTOKEN**" }, function(err, response) {
    //console.log(response.messages);
  });
```

How can I use this within the passport's generated access token.

Answer (score 3):

You need a OAuth2-client:

```
var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2('<CLIENT_ID>', '<CLIENT_SECRET>', '<REDIRECT_URL>');
oauth2Client.setCredentials({ access_token: '<ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE>' });

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  gmail.users.messages.list({ userId: 'me', auth: oauth2Client },
    function(err, response) {
      res.send(response);
    });
}
```

This will work fine for testing with your own credentials, but with more users you have to change access token to the current user's token.